# How can I modify my tkinter code to highlight at different moments multiple occurrences of a word in a Text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

I've got the following code to highlight word-matches within a tk.Text.

However, this code will highlight *all* matches it finds all at once (e.g. if the sentence is "my cat is my friend", it would highlight all occurrences of "my" at the first time I type that word).

How can I modify this code in order to make it highlight only the first occurrence of a word at the first time I pass it through the function, and then when I pass that word through the function a second time, it highlights the next occurrence of that word (so, in my example, it would first highlight "**my** cat is my friend", and then, on a second run, "**my** cat is **my** friend".

Thanks in advance!

```
class CustomText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def highlight_pattern(self, pattern, tag, start="1.0", end="end",
                          regexp=False):
        start = self.index(start)
        end = self.index(end)
        self.mark_set("matchStart", start)
        self.mark_set("matchEnd", start)
        self.mark_set("searchLimit", end)

        count = tk.IntVar()
        while True:
            index = self.search(pattern, "matchEnd","searchLimit",
                                count=count, regexp=regexp)
            if index == "": break
            if count.get() == 0: break # degenerate pattern which matches zero-length strings
            self.mark_set("matchStart", index)
            self.mark_set("matchEnd", "%s+%sc" % (index, count.get()))
            self.tag_add(tag, "matchStart", "matchEnd")
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `while` statement, and executing that code just once?

Comment: @BryanOakley You're correct, Bryan. Your suggestion did what I initially thought I needed. However, I then realized that I actually need the following occurrences of a word to be highlighted as well, on followings runs of that method. I edited my initial post in order to reflect that need. Thank you, though.

Comment: The code you copied allows you to specify where to start looking. The second time you call it, provide an index after the previous match.

Comment: @BryanOakley I apologize for my ignorance. I have been trying to find documentation that explains how these methods work, but I haven't managed to properly understand what this code is doing with what I found... I tried to ask ChatGPT and it did suggest that I save in a variable what the last index was. But in all of my attempts with ChatGPT, my code would either ignore a second occurrence of the word or it would highlight both occurrences at once. I'm still learning to code... Would you be able to assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only need to find one match at a time you can greatly simplify your search function by removing the while loop so that it always searches exactly once.

The search function sets two special marks (indexes) named `matchStart` and `matchEnd`. If you start all but the first search at `matchEnd` it will find the next occurrence after the previous search. For the very first search you can use the index `"1.0"`.

```
class CustomText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def highlight_pattern(self, pattern, tag, start="1.0", end="end", regexp=False):
        count = tk.IntVar()
        index = self.search(pattern, start, end, count=count, regexp=regexp)
        if index != "":
            self.mark_set("matchStart", index)
            self.mark_set("matchEnd", "%s+%sc" % (index, count.get()))
            self.tag_add(tag, "matchStart", "matchEnd")
```

You can then call this function from another function triggered by a button or binding. That function can check to see if `matchEnd` exists, and use the appropriate starting point for the search.

```
text = CustomText(root)
...
def search(event=None):
    start = "1.0" if "matchEnd" not in text.mark_names() else "matchEnd"
    pattern = search_entry.get()
    text.highlight_pattern(pattern, "search", start)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! It finally worked! I realized I had made a huge mistake in my code as well, as I had put the call to this function within a for loop, so obviously it would run more than once. But I really appreciate the explanation, after reading your comment and trying to adapt your code within mine, I was finally able to understand how all of this works. Cheers!